# Angular 2: ngIf inside checkbox directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have this checkbox directive in my Angular RC2 app:

```
export class FormCheckboxDirective {

    @Input() inputId: string;
    @Input() isChecked: string;
    @Input() inputControl: Control;

}
```

that I am using like this:

```
<form-checkbox inputId="showcellphone" [inputControl]="accountForm.controls['showcellphone']" isChecked="{{setting.showCellPhone}}">

    <span label>{{ 'showCellphone' | translate:{value: param} }}</span>

    <div error-message>{{ 'cellphoneError' | translate:{value: param} }}</div>

</form-checkbox>
```

Now, I want to use ngIf inside the directive like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{haserror: !input.valid && !input.pristine}">

    <div class="checkbox">

        <label>

            <input *ngIf="isChecked" type="checkbox" [id]="inputId" #input="ngForm" [ngFormControl]="inputControl" value="1"> <ng-content select="[label]"></ng-content>

        </label>

    </div>

    <div class="input-error-feedback" *ngIf="!input.valid && !input.pristine">
        <ng-content select="[error-message]"></ng-content>
    </div>

</div>
```

But all I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: Shouldn't `@Input() isChecked: string;` be of type boolean?

Comment: Where does the `input` variable come from you reference everywhere?

Comment: Using boolean instead of string gave the same result. The input comes from an observable call to the backend. It's a JSON bool value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by `input` you meant `inputControl`

```ts
<div [ngClass]="{haserror: !inputControl.valid && !inputControl.pristine}">

    <div class="checkbox">

        <label>

            <input *ngIf="isChecked" type="checkbox" [id]="inputId" #input="ngForm" [ngFormControl]="inputControl" value="1"> <ng-content select="[label]"></ng-content>

        </label>

    </div>

    <div class="input-error-feedback" *ngIf="!inputControl.valid && !inputControl.pristine">
        <ng-content select="[error-message]"></ng-content>
    </div>
```